# showing covariant derivative of skew-symmetric rank $2$ tensor vanish

Tags: tensors

> If $A_{ij}$ is a skew-symmetric tensor such that $A_{ij \ , \ k}=A_{ik
>  \ , \ j}$ , prove that $A_{ij \ , \ k}=0$ .

We have $$A_{ij,k}=\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial x^k}-\Gamma^l_{ik}A_{lj}-\Gamma^l_{jk}A_{il}=-\frac{\partial A_{ji}}{\partial x^k}+\Gamma^l_{ki}A_{jl}+\Gamma^l_{kj}A_{li}=-A_{ji,k}$$ which shows that $A_{ij,k}$ is skew-symmetric in $i,j$ . Again $$A_{ij,k}=A_{ik,j}=-A_{ki,j}=-A_{kj,i}$$ which shows $A_{ij,k}$ is skew-symmetric in $i,k$ . But how to use these to show $A_{ij,k}=0$ I don't understand . Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 3):

The tensor $A_{ij,k}$ satisfies two identities, namely $A_{ij,k} = A_{ik,j}$ and $A_{ij,k} = -A_{ji,k}$. If we alternate between the two, we find that

$$A_{ij, k} = A_{ik,j} = -A_{ki,j} = -A_{kj,i} = A_{jk,i} = A_{ji,k} = -A_{ij,k}$$

so $A_{ij,k} = 0$.

Comment: The second property also called symmetry?!

Comment: @C.F.G: Symmetry is probably the wrong word to use in this context. I will reword my answer.